# Expander.Content only applied to one

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to apply style to multiple expanders which will have similar look and functionality. But the problem is that if I style Expander.Content only one of many will have content and the rest are all empty.

[image]

Minimal example:

```
<Style TargetType="Expander" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            Header
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- .... -->

<Expander Grid.Row="0"/>
<Expander Grid.Row="1"/>
<Expander Grid.Row="2"/>
```

as you see only the second row has content (1) during design time. During run time only the last expander has content (1).

If I click on the first expander the content (1) from the third expander actually moved to the first expander.

Why is this happening? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles only create one instance, which for visual elements can only be the child of a single parent. Set the `ContentTemplate` instead of the `Content` directly. *(Templates just describe what is to be created by the control using it, so it can be shared.)*

Comment: why does Header created 3 instances but only one for content?

Comment: @Steve: Because you set it to the string `"Header"`, which is not a *visual element* (unlike the `TextBlock`).

Comment: so all styles only create one instance and share it across all elements it applies to. And if I want to use a visual element inside style but want them to be different between elements then use template. Did I understand it correctly

Comment: @Steve: Yes, you did.

Comment: @Steve: If you want the exact same object you can also define it in a resource dictionary and set `x:Shared` to `false`, then when you reference it in the style via `StaticResource` it will be copied.